# Issues figuring out how to update labels in Tkinter for my Python program

Tags: python, tkinter

So I am writing a Python program in class that uses the Caesar cipher to take a users input and output it as cipher-text. Since i had a lot more time for this project I planned on giving it a GUI in Tkinter. But when I assign the resulted cipher-text to a label it won't display it and keeps it blank. I'm a noob to python and even more to Tkinter so I'm not too keen on being able to fix these issues myself. Here's the code:

```
import string
import collections
import random
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Encoder")
root.geometry("500x400")

def caesar(rotate_string, number_to_rotate_by):

    upper = collections.deque(string.ascii_uppercase)
    lower = collections.deque(string.ascii_lowercase)

    upper.rotate(number_to_rotate_by)
    lower.rotate(number_to_rotate_by)

    upper = ''.join(list(upper))

    lower = ''.join(list(lower))

    return rotate_string.translate(str.maketrans(string.ascii_uppercase, upper)).translate(str.maketrans(string.ascii_lowercase, lower))

def callback():
    print (code)

b = Button(root, text="get", width=10, command=callback)
b.pack()

var = StringVar()

e = Entry(root, textvariable = var)
e.pack()

our_string = e.get()
random_number = random.randint(1,25)
code = caesar(our_string, random_number)


l = Label(root, textvariable=code, anchor=NW, justify=LEFT, wraplength=398)
l.pack()
l.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues with the code you've posted. First and foremost, your callback doesn't do anything besides print the `code` variable. You need to move your call to `caesar` and the associated code into the callback, like so

```
def callback():
    global code
    our_string = e.get()
    random_number = random.randint(1, 25)
    code.set(caesar(our_string, random_number))
```

The second issue that I see is that you need to use a `StringVar` as the `textvariable` argument in your `Label` constructor in order to get the label to update automatically. When all is said and done, my version of your code looks like

```
import string
import collections
import random
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Encoder")
root.geometry("500x400")

code = StringVar()
code.set('Hello')


def caesar(rotate_string, number_to_rotate_by):
    upper = collections.deque(string.ascii_uppercase)
    lower = collections.deque(string.ascii_lowercase)

    upper.rotate(number_to_rotate_by)
    lower.rotate(number_to_rotate_by)

    upper = ''.join(list(upper))

    lower = ''.join(list(lower))

    return rotate_string.translate(str.maketrans(string.ascii_uppercase, upper)).translate(str.maketrans(string.ascii_lowercase, lower))


def callback():
    global code
    our_string = e.get()
    random_number = random.randint(1, 25)
    code.set(caesar(our_string, random_number))

b = Button(root, text="get", width=10, command=callback)
b.pack()

var = StringVar()

e = Entry(root, textvariable=var)
e.pack()
l = Label(root, textvariable=code, anchor=NW, justify=LEFT, wraplength=398)
l.pack()
l.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER)

root.mainloop()
```

This seems to do what you'd expect.

Comment: Thank you so much dude this was a massive amount of help. Thanks for replying so quickly.